# Java - repeating a gradient image horizontally (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gradient, repeat

I'm new to Java GUI. I have two questions. Is there a way to repeat a gradient image horizontally like you would when working with CSS? If not, what is the conventional way of creating a gradient in Java?

Comment: Define 'Java GUI' - Swing? JavaFX? SWT? Something else?

Comment: Since Java itself is just a language you might want to specify which UI library you are using. Is it a rich client application using Swing or JavaFX, a web application (where you'd use CSS anyways, so I guess not), something else?

Answer (score 1):

In Swing, the [GradientPaint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GradientPaint.html) class can be used to draw a gradient. Below is an example that will draw a square containing a linear gradient between white and red (assuming this code is within a class that extends JComponent):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(0,0,Color.WHITE, 100, 0, Color.RED);
    g2d.setPaint(gradient);
    g2d.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
}
```

Comment: Please note the edit I just made: setPaint is defined in Graphics2D, so the parameter Graphics object must be cast to this type